# What are the allowed dimensions for vector fields?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

When one first encounters the concept of vector field, especially in physics, it is often presented just as n-tuple of numbers $(x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n)$ prescribed to each point. In this manner $n$ is allowed to accept arbitrary value.

However, when one proceeds with vector fields in differential geometry, the dimension of a manifold dictates the dimension of a tangent space:

$$\dim M = \dim T_x(M)$$

There are other ways to attach a vector space to each point of manifolds --- tensor products of tangent spaces, p-forms, etc.

Now I ask, given an n-dimensional manifold, what are allowable dimensions for vector spaces on it? Are all of them allowed, or there is no way to naturally construct a k-dimensional vector field (in a broad sense) for certain k?

Another (stronger) version for this question, given n-dimenstional vector space, can we naturally construct k-dimensional vector space from it for arbitrary k?

Comment: $M\times \mathbb{R}^k$ is a $k$ dimensional vector bundle over an $\dim M$ dimensional manifold. This construction always works, for any manifold $M$ and any dimension $k$. You have to specify what "natural" means. This has a precise mathematical meaning, and might be what you are after, but I am not sure...

Comment: Can you help me with this naturality, but without severe category theory? I would call natural what can be encountered in physics --- you have a manifold (and that's all you have), vector bundles on it with what dimensions are physically plausible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a [vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Vector_fields_on_manifolds) is a section of the tangent bundle. Thus it has to have the same dimension as the manifold.

More generally, one can consider [sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle#Sections_and_locally_free_sheaves) of any vector bundle over the manifold. Their dimension is not related to the dimension of the manifold.

Comment: What vector bundles are natural, that is all needed for their existence is the manifold itslef?

Comment: @Yrogirg: Do you mean "needed for their construction" instead of "needed for their existence"? Anyway, I think you are asking the wrong question. The construction of the [spinor bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor_bundle), for instance, depends on more than just the underlying manifold.